# How does accessing a 2D array in C with 1 dimension work

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to understand some C code and I can't wrap my head around the following issues:

- Why does printing an array by accessing it with 1 dimension reverse the order the values in which the stored values print?
- If the array was declared as a `[3][4]` array, is it possible to reference a value at `array[3][x]`?

The author initializes a 2d array - `word[3][4]`, which based on my understanding creates a 3 row/4 column array in memory-

```
         Col 0   Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
Row 0   [0][0]  [0][1]  [0][2]  [0][3]
Row 1   [1][0]  [1][1]  [1][2]  [1][3]
Row 2   [2][0]  [2][1]  [2][2]  [2][3]
```

Later, values are written to the array hardcoding the row and changing the column based on a loop control valriable, `z`, going from `0-3`:

```
word[0][z]
word[1][z]
word[2][z]
word[3][z]
```

At the end, the array is displayed by referencing one dimension:

```
printf("%x", *((unsigned int *)word[i]));
```

This appears to print the values stored in memory in reverse:

```
75757575
42424242
48484849
```

even though they are held in memory as shown below:

```
0xbfa33050: 75757575
0xbfa33054: 42424242
0xbfa33058: 49484848
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to reliably print memory addresses, there is but 1 way of doing so: `printf("%p", (void *) &word[i][0]);` Oh, and your assumption of arrays having columns and rows is wrong: the array looks like this: `0-0|0-1|0-2|0-3|1-0|1-1|1-2|1-3|2-0|2-1|2-2|2-3|`, it's one block of memory, unless you allocate it differently on the heap (an array of pointers)

Comment: That memory allocation diagram makes it a lot clearer...and if I understand it correctly explains why you can print by only providing 1 dimension, as its printing everything that has the same first digit, correct?

Comment: Yup, that also explains why sometimes you can see a matrix being allocated on the heap in a single `malloc` call: `malloc(idx1*idx2*sizeof(type))` returns a pointer that can be accessed like so `var[idx1-1][idx2-1]`. You can _"manually"_ chunk the allocated block, and access it as you see fit. Be careful though, because that can make things a bit more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does printing an array by accessing it with 1 dimension reverse
>   the order the values in which the stored values print?

Because they are stored in contiguous in memory.

> If the array was declared as a [2][3] array, is it possible to
>   reference a 4th row when only 3 were declared?

If you do so, you are trying to access **out of bound elements**.

> This appears to print the values stored in memory in reverse-

Because that's how it is stored in **stack**!

For more details you can refer this image

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the standard **elements of an array are contiguous in memory** (this is the main property of array). So any array no matter what it's dimension has the same representation in memory, using multiply indexes - is syntactic sugar.

Comment: Tracking that, hence the memory output showing all the values sequential in memory. But how does giving the system 1 index tell it to print 4 values? And why are the printed in reverse (I'm assuming something with little endian architecture?)?
And is word[3][z] even possible with a [2][3] initial declaration?

Answer (score 2):

C stores arrays in **row major order**, with row `0` first, then row `1`, and so forth. This image may help you to understand it in a more clear way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're conflating two different issues: array subscripting and endianism.

Take the code

```
int a[2][3] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 };
```

The value at a[x][y] is the value at a[x*3+y].

The value at a[1][2] is the value at a[5] = 5. [Assuming I didn't make any mistakes!]

The apparent reversal of order in memory is because the Intel processor is little endian, so it puts the little end (low byte) of the number first. The memory layout looks like this:

```
00000000
01000000
02000000
03000000
etc
```

That has nothing to do with arrays.