# Symbolic matrices in sympy, print the trace and generate C code

Tags: matrix, sympy

I am new to sympy an would like to print the trace of a symbolic matrix well as generate C code with the function `ccode`

Currently, I have the following:

```
import sympy as sp

# Creates a symbolic matrix (3x3) with symbol A
A = sp.MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 3)

# Trace of a matrix
traceM=sp.Trace(A)

# Generate C code
print(sp.ccode(traceM))
```

If I print (sp.pprint) matrix A, I will get:

```
In [49]:sp.pprint(sp.Matrix(A))
```

[image]

If I print the the trace of A, the following error appears

```
In [50]:sp.pprint(sp.Matrix(traceM))

TypeError: 
Data type not understood; expecting list of lists or lists of values.
```

I was hopping to get [image].

Additionally, If I try to generate C code from the trace I will get the following message

```
In [51]: print(sp.ccode(traceM))
// Not supported in C:
// Trace
Trace(A)
```

and I was hopping for:

```
A[0, 0]+A[1, 1]+A[2, 2]
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Note: if I use a numpy function (`traceM=numpy.trace(A)`) it will give me the expected result... but I should be able to obtain the same with sympy...

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

So, I think the aim here would be to unroll that trace expression, and have it be replaced by the explicit sum. The only way I found to do that unrolling process was through the use of [rewrite](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#rewrite) (I was hinted at this because the Trace class has a method called [_eval_rewrite_as_Sum](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/d14f9ad8fbc8ac8cc9bdebd61d2ec58fda507ba2/sympy/matrices/expressions/trace.py#L115) )

The module being used to generate the C source code is the [codegen module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/codegen.html) (also see Aaron Meurer's nice [codegen](https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/) tutorial and its [github repo](https://github.com/sympy/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial)).

This was tested on SymPy 1.7

```py
import sympy as sp
from sympy.utilities.codegen import codegen
N=3
A = sp.MatrixSymbol('A', N, N)
traceM = sp.Trace(A).rewrite(sp.Sum)
[(c_name, c_code), (h_name, c_header)] = codegen(("f", traceM), "C89", "test", header=False, empty=False)
print(c_code)
```

The result was this:

```cc
#include "test.h"
#include <math.h>
double f(double *A) {
   double f_result;
   f_result = A[0] + A[4] + A[8];
   return f_result;
}
```

One thing to notice is that the 2D array A [is accessed as a 1-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22455017/827519).